# Send ArrayList object from jsp to Spring controller

Tags: hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

This is Gaurav. I am new in Spring mvc and hibernate .The requirement is Student has multiple degree details like board_name scheool/college, year of passing.[Please see the attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TujTJ.jpg) The question is how to bind the Degree deails in JSP page and send it to Spring controller. Thanks in advance.

Comment: show us the code which you tried till now

Comment: Welcome to SO @Gaurav, to learn Spring and Hibernate there are many tutorials present on web. First try them out and if you face any problem we are here to help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the degree info is stored in a list named degreeList in your model object. The name of the inputs in each row of the degree details will be `degreeList[<rowIndex>].<fieldName>` (e.g. for the ID input in the first row, it will be `<input name="degreeList[0].id" />`). From that, the spring controller can get the list of degree detail in your student model.